# How to put a label on an issue in GitHub if you are not a contributor / owner?

Tags: github

I've submitted an issue for a project on GitHub which is not mine and I'm not a contributor, but I cannot find a way to label my issue. Is there a way for me to label it, or is this only available for contributors?

Comment: Hmm, years later and still not possible :(

Comment: Bump. This is sorely needed. A preliminary label the user can set. The user knows if he is sending a "question", "feature request", or a "bug report". But the user doesn't have a formalised way of stating the type of issue, so they all end up in the same pile of unlabelled issues.

Comment: 8 years later and still not possible

Answer (score 296, accepted):

It's only available for contributors.

This way, you can avoid random people assigning the wrong labels and messing up your categories.

It would however be useful if you could in some manner propose labels. Then you could mark an issue as what you think is a bug, so the owner can just confirm that. Many people suggest labels in the title: `[proposed Label] actual title`

Comment: As the owner of a number of GitHub projects, I see this as a feature.

Comment: OK, that explains why I can't add a label. But what might be the rationale behind such a limitation being in place?

Comment: The labels are a way for the contributors to divide the issues into categories. They can help you to mark priority and such.

If everyone were allowed to label their issues, this structure would be lost.

Comment: @Andy Lester Yes, I also see it in the projects I own. I'm just wondering about the projects I use and am not a contributor for, since I'd like to label my issues for those as well.

Comment: @Noctua Yes, I see that. But why can't non-contributors label an issue? I'd like to know the rationale for that.

Comment: I see it as a feature rather than a bug because I don't want people coming and reassigning priorities or labels on my issues, especially since there is no audit trail.  If someone posts a useless comment, I can delete it, but if they change a label, then I have no idea that that happened.

Comment: @AndyLester the ability to change something is different to the ability to add something. Having different access to labels or protection over certain labels or labels fixed by contributors would make a lot more sense, and reduce the admin for those running repositories.

Comment: I feel like a prick every time I submit something I clearly know to be a feature request as an issue...  It would be nice to have a better way than just writing "feature request" in the body to indicate that that's the case.

Comment: @AndyLester Right, I get that, it would be cool if there was a way for an issue submitter to *suggest* a label though -- just so that the contributors can kind of have some context going into the thing "Oh, this is just a feature request..." or "Oh, this is a bug on the homepage and not with the project", etc...

Comment: I see a lot of people just title the issue with the label they think it should be enclosed in sqr braces. Exp: "[Feature Req] This would be a good feature"

Comment: Don't feel guilty for calling an RFE an "issue". That's exactly why Github chose the word "Issue" instead of "Bug". You're not claiming it's a bug - the contributors decide that.

Comment: I also feel like a nob asking a question and it comes up as an issue.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

I see this as as bug. The UI does not give any clear reason why you cannot assign a label to an issue, so you end up wasting time trying to figure out if you are misunderstanding something, and then getting all frustrated feeling stupid.

If GitHub's design intent was to make their users feel frustrated and stupid, then the design is a total success.

If GitHub's design intent was NOT to make their users feel frustrated and stupid, then the design is a disaster.

Comment: While I understand why it's set up this way, I think the documentation is suboptimal. I wasted a couple of minutes trying to figure out how to label an issue I posted, since the github help describes how to add a label without ever mentioning that the functionality isn't available to all users. I should have just gone to SO first for the answer.

Comment: While we're here, is there standard etiquette for labelling your feature request? Prefixing the title with "[feature request]", or putting it in the body, or assuming the maintainers will label it themselves? Can they edit the title later to remove the [tag] once a proper GitHub tag has been applied?

Comment: @DavidLord You usually preceed the title with [...], if it's a bug report. Feature requests are usually quite clear from the body. Mind you, since the issue templates, a lot of repositories have guidelines included. Owners can edit issue titels.

Comment: @AndyLester, @ Noctua. Spend some time around other communities and you can see a lot of different and new ideas.. Years ago there was a Quora thread with a suggestion on something like this, which leads to the discussion on the purpose of tags, and the consensus/conclusion was that each class of searcher need their own tags. **There's nothing stopping a thread from having multiple tag views.** One is for the project owner, and the other only shows up in each user's profile.

Comment: I don't see why not let me as a random user put the tag the way I see it, if I'm right I've just spared some work for the contributor and everybody is happy, if I'm not he can change it like he would anyways.

Comment: @Eric Kolotyluk totally agree with you.  I just opened an issue and I want to label it as "enhancement" but I just can't figure out how to do it.  The UI should give the person who open the issue a chance to label it (but only once so that non-owner/contributor cannot mess up any label put there in the future by the developers), or at the very least give a "label" button and then explain that only the owner/contributors can label the issue.

Answer (score 28):

**GitHub issue templates labels (`.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/XXX.md`, December 2018)**

Documentation: https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-issue-templates-for-your-repository

With this feature, repository admins can create a set of issue templates, and assign a set of labels to each template.

Then, whenever an user creates a new issue, even non admins, they can choose between one of the templates, and if they do, the labels get automatically assigned! Once assigned at creation, labels cannot be changed later on by the non-admins.

Here is a test repo of mine that you can freely create issues on to test it out: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-web-interface/issues/new/choose Previously the URL was: just https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-web-interface/issues/new but now as of November 2023 you need the `/choose` subpath or else you go to the new issue creation directly without templates

This is how it looks like when the user is about to create an issue with a template:

[image]

The issue template feature is much older, but the labels were an update from December 2018 https://github.blog/changelog/2018-12-05-issue-template-automation-improvements/

I like this approach, because it effectively allows you to determine a subset of labels that anybody can create, while still potentially reserving other labels for collaborators only.

The templates can be created from GitHub's repo Settings tab, but even if you do it from there it just generates magic files under the `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE` directory, see e.g.: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-web-interface/tree/7f2bb195ff303a037499c1c349b3c89158221674/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE which is good as it keeps more repo metadata inside the repo.

The directory could contain something like:

.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/bug.md

```
---
name: bug
about: Use this template to report existing bugs.
title: 'Bug'
labels: bug

---
```

.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/feature-request.md

```
---
name: feature-request
about: Use this template to request new features.
title: 'Feature request'
labels: feature-request

---
```

**Old answer**

I have submitted this request to `support@github.com` and https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/148 and pointed to this question.

[@jdennes](https://github.com/jdennes) replied with the usual neutral:

> I've added a +1 to this item on our Feature Request List for consideration.

which confirms it is not possible.

Let's upvote this question to heavens until they do it!

Comment: So what's the progress so far?

Comment: @Pacerier update: issue templates now solve the problem nicely!